# Full Drupal migrate from 7 to 10, site using CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, civicrm

I manage a website based on Drupal 7 where we use CiviCRM

I would like to migrate to Drupal 10, but I have a lot of doubts about this procedure...

Can you recommend any materials that reliably describe and help in such a process, courses, training or instructions?

Comment: There is a civicrm channel where you will find a lot more eyeballs of folk who have done this I expect https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/